How Does Random Cropping and Resizing Affect the Distribution of Features in Image Classification
I am working on an image classification task using deep learning. My network extracts features from an image using a feature extractor and then passes these features to a classifier for image classification. Assuming both the feature extractor and the classifier are well-trained, the network should produce the correct classification results.
Now, let's assume that I input a $224\times224$ image into the feature extractor.
The extracted feature $f$ would follow a distribution, $f\sim N(\mu_\alpha, \sigma_\alpha^2)$, where
$\alpha$ represents the label of the image, and I assume that the features are well-separated.
Now, I randomly crop the image to a $112\times112$ size and then resize it back to $224\times 224$ and passing it through the feature extractor.
Then, does the feature $f_{cropped}$ still follows the same distribution as $f$?
If it is not, what distribution does $f_{cropped}$ follow?
